# Java getting all combinations of Player / Strategy for NashEquilibrium

Tags: java, eclipse, combinations

I'm trying to compute a Nash Equilibirum therefor I need all possible combinations of Players and their Strategies.

I've got the classes and methods:

- `Strategy`
- `Player` with `LinkedList<Strategy> strategies`
- `StrategyCombination` with `TreeMap<Player, Strategy> combination`
- `boolean isNashEquilibrium()` which tests if a StrategyCombination is a NashEquilibrium

this all works fine. Now for a given List of Players and their Strategies, I want to compute all possible StrategyCombinations and test every Combination for isNashEquilibirum. I just can't figure out how. I guess an recursive algorithm would be possible.

so far I've got:

```
        public class Game {

        LinkedList<Player> players = new LinkedList<Player>();

        public Game(){
        }

        public void addPlayer(Player p){
            this.players.add(p);
        }

        public StrategyCombination computeNashEquilibrium(){

            StrategyCombination nash = null;

            StrategyCombination sc = new StrategyCombination();

            for(int i = 0; i < this.players.size(); i++){
                    sc.combination.put(this.players.get(i), this.players.get(i).strategies.get(0));
            }

            for(int i = 0; i <= this.players.size()-1; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j <= this.players.get(i).strategies.size()-1; i++){
                    StrategyCombination sc2 = sc.createNew(this.players.get(i).strategies.get(j)); /* makes a new StrategyCombination with one Strategy replaced */
                if(sc2.isNashEquilibrium){
                nash = sc2;
                }
                    for(int k = i+1; k <= this.players.size()-1; i++){
                        for(int l = i+1; l <= this.players.size()-1; l++){
                            sc2.createNew(...);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return nash;
        }
```

So how can I get all StrategyCombinations? Even Brute Force is ok I just can't figure it out right now :/. Thanks for the read and the responses. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Permutation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html) if order of things is needed

Use [Combinations](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Combinations.java.html) if order of things is not needed

Answer (score 0):

You could separate setup from simulation...

Usually, it is to implement combinatory with recursion.

Pseudo-code example:

```
createSetup(listOfplayers, listOfStrategies, indexOfPlayer){
    for each strategy of listOfStrategies
       assign strategy to indexOfPlayer-th player
       if (isLastPlayer()){
            executeSimluation(listOfPlayers);
       } else {
            createSetup(listOfplayers, listOfStrategies, indexOfPlayer+1);
       }
}
```